# Is it possible to do Flutter Firebase drop-in UI authentication?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'd like to create my first flutter app and use Firebase drop-in UI authentication. (Target platforms are web, Android, and iOS.)

When I search for instructions, there is a maze of outdated documentation and related things that I'm not looking for. I'm wondering if the drop-in authentication UI is available with flutter at all.

The video in the flutter documentation for the firebase integration doesn't use the drop-in UI. It instead has one re-create an entire authentication flow in the UI and simply call Firebase methods for backend functionality. I'm trying to get a prototype running fast and not re-invent authentication.

What is the fastest way with flutter to get user authentication working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a SignInScreen class that seems to do the drop-in UI authentication.

I found an updated version of a codelab that shows how to use it: https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-get-to-know-flutter#4

There were a million dependency issues and pointers to deprecated things and new things that needed to be imported. I'm not sure what got it working, but it seems to be doing the whole sign in flow.

Autogenerated class documentation:
https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_ui/latest/firebase_ui/SignInScreen-class.html